# Actions.key not working react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am implementing a button that when pressed goes to a new screen using react-native-router-flux.

```
import {Scene, Router, Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';

 render() {

    <Router>
      <Scene key="root">
        <Scene key="settings" component={App}/>
      </Scene>
    </Router>

  return (
    <View>
      <Animated.View style={{position: "absolute", width: "100%", backgroundColor: THEME_COLOR, zIndex: 1}}>
        <Header style={{backgroundColor: THEME_COLOR}} hasTabs>
          <Body>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => (Actions.settings)} style= {{alignSelf: 'flex-end'}}>

                <Text style={{color: "white"}}>
                  Settings
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
          <Title>
            <Animated.Text style={{color: 'white', fontWeight: "bold"}}>
              Messages
            </Animated.Text>
          </Title>
          </Body>
        </Header>
      </Animated.View>
```

But when i click the button (atm its just text that says 'settings') nothing happens, have i implemented the Router component incorrectly or am i calling it wrong?

Comment: `onPress={ () => (Action.settings)}` returns the actual function Action.settings which does nothing, you might want to run the function with `onPress={Action.settings}` or `onPress={ () => Action.settings()}` but i dont know enough about this router.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either, it fails and says that it is not a function.

Comment: Is it even there? before the return, add a `console.log(Action.settings)` and check, else you probably need to import Action from somewhere.

Comment: Hmm, nothing appears..

Comment: Then you have missed a step somewhere, you need to either define or import Action, or if its a prop sent into the component, let me check their manual

Comment: Ok you want to add `import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux'` at the top of your js file.

Comment: I have that, sorry I should have shown all relevant code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166329/discussion-between-krs-and-andrew-orourke).

Comment: Add `<Scene key="settings" component={Settings}/>` to the `Stack`. then call `onPress={() => { Action.settings(); }}`